# field cannot be blank only on a certain view infopath

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have a field that is only on a certain view(which isn't the first one) and I want to set it to cannot be blank. Is there anyway I can do this without it throwing the error that its blank on the other views

Comment: Why is it throwing the cannot be blank error when its not even there in the other views? Do you have a validation rule in the other views which is referring to that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dummy field. This dummy field will indicate if the required field, whether on this view or other views, if it is filled out. Use values 0 and 1.

Example: On View B, Field B (required) is blank. The dummy field value should be 0. Put a rule on Field B that when answered or has value, will set dummy field to 1 and when blank, 0.

In this case, you can disable the button on view B or anything that you like to prevent submitting when on view B. View A will have no connection on that view since you only disable the submit button on view B based on the dummy field.